# Blazor Wasm Identity Login/Logout event

Tags: authentication, blazor, identityserver4, webassembly

In a .Net 5 Blazor WASM app using the standard identity from the Wasm template, I want to do something when a user logs in (or logs out).  I've tried the RemoteAuthenticatorView in Authentication.razor:

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" 
                         OnLogInSucceeded="OnLoginSucceeded"
                         OnLogOutSucceeded="OnLogoutSucceeded1"
                         />


@code{
    [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }



    public async void OnLoginSucceeded()
    {
        // do something
    }

    public void OnLogoutSucceeded1()
    {
        // do something
    }

}
```

and also, I tried in a component (where I really want to take the action to merge a shopping basket) :

```
AuthenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += OnAuthenticationStateChanged;


 private async void OnAuthenticationStateChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
    {
        var user = (await task).User;
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff") + " InitialDataLoader -> OnAuthenticationStateChanged -> IsUserAuthenticated: " + user.Identity.IsAuthenticated);

    }
```

I have breakpoints in each method and after I finally hit the Login breakpoint in both the RemoteAuthenticatorView  and my component (it didn't break  at all for a while), it now breaks but once only.  If I logout - no logout event.  If I login again, even as another user, I don't hit the breakpoints.

Is there a consistent method to generate or detect a login?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was working ok, just the breakpoints were not working - no idea why not.  I added Console.WriteLine messages to each & all events are hit correctly.  So both techniques work as expected.

Comment: breakpoints dont work in Blazor until initialization is over...